Are all simple groups of order coprime to 3 cyclic? If so, why?
The two paragraphs immediately below are motivation.  My two questions themselves are numbered at the end of the post.
I've got a problem involving simple groups of coprime-to-$p$ order that, for Lie-theoretic reasons to do with outer-automorphism groups, is only an issue when $p$ equals $2$ or $3$.  Of course, groups of odd order are soluble, so, for $p = 2$, I need only worry about cyclic groups of odd, prime order, and I can handle that case.  So let's consider $p = 3$.
Obviously, the orders of the alternating groups on $n$ letters with $n \ge 5$ are divisible by $3$.  I went down the list of finite simple groups, visited the articles on sporadic groups linked there and discovered that each has order divisible by $3$, and, with the aid of Artin - The orders of the classical simple groups, believe I have observed that the order of every classical group over a field of order $q$ is divisible by $\frac1{\gcd(4, q^2 - 1)}q(q^2 - 1)$, which is always divisible by $3$.

I'm a little suspicious of this sort of proof by (as I seem to remember Tits saying somewhere) "un coup d'œil."  Is the conclusion (that all simple groups of order coprime to $3$ are cyclic) correct?

If the conclusion is correct, is there any classification-free proof of it, or even any conceptual reason (aside from "funny things happen for small primes") that I should have expected it?



No, there order $29120$ gives a counterexample.

@Peter, re, thanks!  What group is that?

However , it is true that the order of a nonabelian finite simple group must be divisible by $12$ or by $20$

@Peter, re, thanks!  I guess your group was ${^2B_2(2^3)}$, as referenced in @‍testaccount's answer.

A wild question! :) :)

I think the expression would be "un coup d'œil" (without the definite article).

@MikhailKatz, re, thanks!  I've edited accordingly.  (I'd actually Googled first to check that I had the phrase right, and didn't even notice the difference between the result and what I had in mind.)

There's a unique family of nonabelian finite simple groups of order prime to $3$. These were discovered by Suzuki around 1960, and are appropriately named the Suzuki groups, $\text{Sz}(2^n)$, $n$ odd, $n > 1$. Suzuki discovered them in his investigation of a certain class of finite permutation groups known as Zassenhaus groups, which are $2$-transitive permutation groups in which no nonidentity element fixes $3$ (or more) points. Later they were understood to be twisted groups of Lie type – the fixed points of an automorphism of order $2$ acting on $\text{Sp}(4, 2^n)$, where $\text{Sp}(4, q)$ is the $4$-dimensional symplectic group over a field of order $q$.
Feit was also studying Zassenhaus groups at this time. He had arrived at the case which led to the Suzuki gropus and knew that these groups would necessarily have order not divisible by $3$, and so he didn't pursue this case any further. Also, Feit had come around a copy of Burnside's "Theory of Groups of Finite Order" which contains the conjecture (in Appendix N(?)) that all finite simple groups have order divisible by $2$. In the margin of the book, Dickson had also written the note "also by $3$". Burnside was right, Dickson was wrong.
The following is now a theorem:
Let $G$ be a nonabelian finite simple group whose order is not divisible by $3$. Then $G$ is isomorphic to $\text{Sz}(2^{2n + 1})$ for some $n > 0$.
This theorem was announced by Thompson around 1970, but a proof was never published by him. The first published proof was given by Glauberman around 1976. Glauberman in fact classified all nonabelian finite simple groups $G$ such that $G$ has no subgroups $N$ and $H$ with $N$ normal in $H$ and $H/N$ isomorphic to the symmetric group of degree $3$... so-called $S_4$-free groups. His proof relied on a theorem of Goldschmidt classifying finite simple groups having a nonidentity strongly closed abelian $2$-subgroup. A better proof of Glauberman's theorem was found and published some years later by Stellmacher.
At the heart of the Glauberman-Stellmacher work is the following observation:
Let $H$ be a finite group with a normal subgroup $N$ such that $N$ is a $2$-group and $C_H(N) = Z(N)$ i.e. if $x$ is an element of $H$ which commutes with every element of $N$, then $x$ is in $N$ (and hence in $Z(N)$, the center of $N$). Then if $|H|$ is not divisible by $3$ and $T$ is a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $H$, you can always (I think) find a nonidentity characteristic subgroup $C$ of $T$ which is normal in $H$ i.e. $C$ is normal both in $\text{Aut}(T)$ and in $H$.
This fails if $H = S_4$. In this case, $N$ is a Klein $4$-subgroup of $H$ and $N$ is the only nonidentity subgroup of $T$ which is normal in $H$. But $T$ has two Klein $4$-subgroups which are interchanged in $\text{Aut}(T)$. So, $N$ is not a characteristic subgroup of $T$.
The history of this line of reasoning goes back to Thompson's work on factorization and failure of factorization. The group $S_4$ is the root of all failure of factorization.
Now if there's no failure of factorization, you're led to the situation (via Alperin's theorem on local control of fushion) where a Sylow $2$-subgroup $T$ of $G$ has a nonidentity abelian $2$-subgroup $A$ such that no element of $A$ is $G$-conjugate to any element of $T - A$. Then we say that $A$ is a strongly closed abelian $2$-subgroup of $G$, and as mentioned already, such groups were classified by Goldschmidt.
As a straightforward exercise one can prove:
Let $A$ be an abelian $2$-group of exponent $2$. Let $G$ be a finite group in which $A$ is a normal subgroup and $C_G(A) = A$. Suppose that $G/A$ is a dihedral group of order $2p$, for some odd prime $p$. Let $T$ be a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$. Then $A$ is a characteristic subgroup of $T$ (in fact, $A$ is the Thompson subgroup of $T$), unless $p = 3$ and $G = X \times S$, where $Z = Z(G)$ and $S$ is isomorphic to $S_4$.

This is an incredible answer!  Do you have references for the work of Glauberman and Stellmacher?  A casual search turned up Stellmacher - A characteristic subgroup of $\Sigma_4$-free groups; is that the right place to look?

@LSpice: see this article and references therein.

I would like to acknowledge your answer in a paper.  Are you willing to tell me your name, so that I may credit you?  You can find my e-mail at https://faculty.tcu.edu/lspice .

No, it is not true.
The Suzuki groups are famous for being the only finite non-abelian simple groups with order coprime to $3$.

I am very grateful for this precise answer that quickly and clearly dispelled my over-optimistic hopes.  I am sorry that the sheer volume of history and context in @user531372's answer means that I have to switch my acceptance over to that one.

I would like to acknowledge your answer in a paper.  Are you willing to tell me your name, so that I may credit you?  You can find my e-mail at https://faculty.tcu.edu/lspice .
